# Text and Image Alignment in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to keep a space between "Let your Style Speaks" and "Discover..." text.  also want to align the image down from the top a little bit. here's my code and please help me to do those changes. I was trying but I'm unable to do this. can someone please send where want to be edited. I have attached UI for your reference. this is the current UI I want to be changed
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Auth Screen 1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,

        //primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        // scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,

        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline4:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          // button: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
          headline6:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.2),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //   appBar: AppBar(
      //
      // backgroundColor: Color(0XFFd5ae48),
      //   ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0XFFd5ae48),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
             // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/girl.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            flex: 2,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,bottom:10),
                  child: RichText(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    text: TextSpan(
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "Let Your\nStyles Speaks\n",
                          style: TextStyle( fontFamily: 'Sen',fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,fontSize: 30) ,
                        ),
                        
                        TextSpan(
                          text:
                              "Discover the latest trends in women fashion and explore your personality\n",
                          style: TextStyle( fontFamily: 'Sen',fontSize: 15) ,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                FittedBox(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return HomePage();
                        },
                      ));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 26, vertical: 16),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),

                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "Get started",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily:'sen',
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20),
                                ),

                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SafeArea` for the app bar and in `RichText` you can use text span as `<InlineSpan>` and then you can able to use `WidgetSpan`. That helps you to use space between two spans.

`TextSpan` Part

```
TextSpan(
                        children: <InlineSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "Let Your\nStyles Speaks\n",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Sen',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 30),
                          ),
                          WidgetSpan(
                              child: Container(
                            height: 30,
                          )),
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                "Discover the latest trends in women fashion and explore your personality\n",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Sen', fontSize: 15),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
```

complete code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Auth Screen 1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,

        //primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        // scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,

        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline4:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          // button: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
          headline6:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.2),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //   appBar: AppBar(
      //
      // backgroundColor: Color(0XFFd5ae48),
      //   ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0XFFd5ae48),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/test.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              flex: 2,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 10),
                    child: RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        children: <InlineSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "Let Your\nStyles Speaks\n",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Sen',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontSize: 30),
                          ),
                          WidgetSpan(
                              child: Container(
                            height: 30,
                          )),
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                "Discover the latest trends in women fashion and explore your personality\n",
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Sen', fontSize: 15),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  FittedBox(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return Container();
                          },
                        ));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 26, vertical: 16),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Get started",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'sen',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check out this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.